# Mongoose Node: How to refer one object array in another object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have got two schemas- user and vendor and trying to save vendor array in user mongo document. I am trying to create reference array like this;

```
vendors: { type: 'array', of: { type: 'Vendor'} }
```

This throws following error;

> TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object at
>   Function.defineProperty (native)

I have also tried creating refrence object like this;

```
vendors: [Vendor]
```

This time no error is thrown but vendor is not saved in user

Comment: It should be more like this `vendors:[{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'vendor'}]`

Comment: @Molda Thanks for getting back to me. Using this will lead to save ObjectId in user after vendor is saved in a seperate collection i.e. Instead I want to save complete vendor objects in this array reference.

Comment: @Techphile, What you have tried to save the vendor data in user? Show your code here...

Comment: OK sorry i misunderstood what you need. So can you show how are you trying to save vendor when using *vendors: [Vendor]*

Comment: Another way could be to define the vendor inside the vendors array like this `vendors:[{name: String, title: String}]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// instantiate user model
var User = mongoose.model('User');  // Assumed that you named your model `User`
var user = new User({
  name: 'test',
  gender: 'male',
  vendors: vendor  // vendor model schema instance
});

// save the user
user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('User created!');
});
```

Hope this will help you to resolve issue !!